# How can I find out how much a passenger window of a Boeing 737 costs?

Tags: boeing-737, boeing, windows

Where do I have to look to find out how much a passenger window of a Boeing 737 costs?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! The answer to your question depends on the specific aircraft variant (in your case, like the Boeing 737, 747, 777, etc), the airline, etc. You need to be much more specific to get a good answer. Also I don't think it is even possible to buy a window, as they are 'made to order' for that specific aircraft. I think the price can be found with a little effort though...

Comment: Sorry that I did not specify the aircraft model. I want to know for the Boeing 737 model. I need it in 90 ea. but want to know in the unit price.

Comment: I didn't get you right - did you mean to say that you want 90 windows of a Boeing 737?

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually I may need more but at the very early state it will be 90 ea. (and will increased).

Comment: Out of curiosity, might I know why you need 90 windows of a Boeing 737?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, quotations cannot be provided.

Comment: Agree, I have already got the right response from "fooot". This question should be closed.

Comment: *"I have already got the right response from "fooot". This question should be closed."* That's not what closure is for. See [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) and [*cast close and reopen votes* privilege](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) in the [help].

Comment: Just out of curiousity, did you accidentally break one and are feeling guilty about it, or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This page](https://www.zauba.com/import-WINDOW+ASSEMBLY+PARTS/hs-code-88033000-hs-code.html) has declared values for part shipments, including one with the 140N2139-4, which is the assembly containing the seal, mid pane, and outer pane for the 737 NG. The declared value is 24,562 INR which is currently about 375 USD. A shipment of 20 also listed has a lower unit price.

For searching purposes GKN has part numbers in [their catalog.](http://www.gkngroup.com/GKNChina/GKN%20in%20China/Business%20Overview/Brochures/Boeing%20737%20Product%20Datasheet.pdf) You typically have to ask for a quote from suppliers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are referring to a Boeing 737, here what you might be looking for:

- [GKN Aerospace](https://www.gkn.com/en/our-divisions/gkn-aerospace/)
- [Boeing 737 Passenger windows](https://www.gkn.com/en/our-divisions/gkn-aerospace/our-solutions/special-products/transparencies/#anchoritem3)
- [Passenger Window Datasheet](http://www.gkngroup.com/GKNChina/GKN%20in%20China/Business%20Overview/Brochures/Boeing%20737%20Product%20Datasheet.pdf)

But as these are made-to-order (as I mentioned in my comment), there is no MRP / MSRP - you have to directly contact them to get a quote. The actual unit price depends on your application, the quantity of windows you need, and other such factors.

EDIT: If certification isn't necessary, you might as well look for aircraft bone-yards, where you *might* get windows, which will be way cheaper than certified, made-to-order units. (Courtesy: @DanPichelman)

Comment: Dear Anand, Your provided info is very helpful. I want to know the unit cost but 90 ea. is the approx qty to estimate the best price. Anyway you have already help with the useful direction that how can I proceed. Thank you again for your attention.

Comment: Valuable information, but not an answer. It should be a comment (unless you provide a price for a bundle of 20 windows).

Comment: @mins, I think you are correct in saying that - what would you like me to do next? Should I delete the post? Add more details of pricing?

Comment: Now it is here, let's see what happens to the question.

Comment: I wonder why someone who wants to buy 90 (!) Boeing windows doesn't ask Boeing. I mean, this isn't like _"I want to buy one for display or decoration"_

Comment: @PerlDuck: Is he building a Private Jet with massive windows?

Comment: If the OP doesn't require certified parts, a boneyard might be an option.

Comment: @DanPichelman: Great Idea! With your permission, shall I add this to my post?

Comment: Go ahead and add it